# keyboard input doesnt work on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, visual-studio-2015

I have a project that I was having no problems editing before, but now for some odd reason, has restricted me from editing it. Whenever I try to type anything into the file, it doesn't type the character. It seems to be a problem exclusively with the keyboard input because I can copy and paste just fine. It also doesn't seem to be a program wide problem either, because I can edit xaml with no problem, its just the JS file that I am having an issue with.

I am able to delete, backspace and use the arrow keys, but none of the numbers or letters.

I am using visual studio 2015 community. If anyone can help me... PLEASE!

Comment: Some issue, also with JS and TS files.

Answer (score 0):

It may not help (and I assume you have tried this) but I just had a similar problem and simply shut down Visual Studios and re-opened it. After that it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Cf. last answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468316/visual-studio-2019-keyboard-stops-responding-or-continously-repeats-characters):

*A workaround seems to be to open a pull-down menu, such as the File menu, and close it again.*

This worked for me today on VS 2022 17.4.4 on which I had the issue with the keyboard not working every time I was running a unit test from a Resharper Unit Test Session.