# Copy/Paste line in Visual Studio 2015 seems broken

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I frequently use the "copy/paste line" functionality of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Visual Studio (when nothing is selected, it copies the entire line).  In past versions, when I pasted the line, it would always be inserted above the line my cursor is on, regardless of where the cursor is on the line.

In Visual Studio 2015, it seems this is broken or at least non-deterministic.  See the screen capture below (note that it Visual Studio is in "safe mode", started with `devenv.exe /safemode`):

[image: Screen capture of copy and paste line being strange]

I'm only ever pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, but you can see sometimes it inserts the copied line *at the cursor* and sometimes inserts the copied line *above the cursor*.

I've tried toggling the only option that looks like it applies, *Text Editor*, *All Languages*, *Apply Cut or Copy commands to blank lines when there is no selection*, but it makes no difference.

Does anyone else see this behavior?

Comment: It's hard to see in your video when exactly you invoke copy and paste. Could you please describe one "bad" scenario? Also, it works for me as expected (although not in the safe mode; was that important?)

Comment: @VladFeinstein The first and second copies are bad (line 3 and then line 2).  The next 4 are good copies, then the last one is bad.  My only order of actions is move the cursor, copy, paste, repeat. I tried in Safe Mode to ensure no plugins were causing this.  It seems to be somewhat random when it works and when it doesn't, though for me it performs "bad" copies more often than not.

Comment: I do have a similar problem with CTRL+V. It sometimes just stops working. I then have to use CTRL+SHIFT+V.

Comment: Sometimes I can no longer entry any letters or numbers. I can move the cursor with the keyboard and copy/past is also working with the keyboard. For that, I did not yet find a workardound. see [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888530/keyboard-input-doesnt-work-on-visual-studio

Comment: I have been having the same problem. It's maddening. The only thing that I've found that helps is hitting CTRL+C a few times to copy. It may also help to do that before cutting the line.

Answer (score 2):

I found a possible solution/reason for this issue today.  This behavior is much more prevalent when I have a [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) connection window open, and after a few hours of testing, I have yet to see this problem when no VNC session is open.

This application monitors the clipboard as well as the mouse and keyboard, so it's possible that something it is doing interferes with this functionality of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It is not broken. But the keys are mismatched. Ctrl+C is assigned to File.CloseAllButThis option. Go to Tools => Options => Environment => keyboard. Find command for File.CloseAllButThis, remove currently assigned key ( should have Ctrl + C), and assign it some other combination such as Alt+C. Find Edit.Copy command and assign it Ctrl + C. You should have copy paste working fine.

Comment: Ctrl+C is assigned to copy on my machine, not CloseAllButThis.

Answer (score 0):

Issue: copy/paste not working. Cursor in block mode, not line mode.

Solution: uninstalled each extension one at a time. Closed program, and restarted. Kept a list of the uninstalls in a text file, so I can decide what to reinstall later. The extension called "Vim" was causing me the issue.

Running on:
VS Code version 1.26.1, Windows 8.1