# Visual Studio 2019 keyboard stops responding or continously repeats characters

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard, visual-studio-2019, resharper, stylecop

Using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise (v16) (with Resharper and StyleCop extension for Resharper installed) regularly has the following issues with the keyboard (many times per day).

1. Keys entered on the keyboard are not input
2. Keys entered on the keyboard get input in the wrong order (even typing slowly), like this:

[image]

3. Keys entered (including CTRL+V) get repeated continuously, like this:

[image]

The only way to temporarily resolve it is to close visual studio and re-open where it will work fine for 5-60 minutes before the problem reoccurs.

Steps taken:

1. Replace the cheap external keyboard with a more expensive one (Logitech G213)
2. Unplug all USB devices except for mouse and keyboard
3. Reinstall Visual Studio

None of these steps have resolved the issue.
I have not yet tried uninstalling Resharper/Stylecop as I do require these for my every day work.

Has anyone seen/solved this problem before?

Comment: Yes. I updated ReSharper to the latest version yesterday. Since then, VS hangs then repeats the character I typed many times. VS is then un-responsive and suggests I disable ReSharper.

I've never seen this behaviour before after years of ReSharper usage. It makes no difference if I use the laptop keyboard or an external wireless one.

Comment: Accepted answer solves it. Also Resharper have admitted the bug and will release a patch this week aparently.

Comment: Oh the accepted answer was you I see. Hope it solved it for you too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the link [from the ReSharper forums](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4403747662994). This shows a workaround and a response. I also saw the empty document issue reported there too.

I'm going to give it a try or rollback if necessary.

Comment: The issues described on the Resharper form link you sent are _exactly_ what I am having (including the ones mentioned on there that I didn't include in my question for brevity).

I have disabled Inlay Hits and will post back here shortly to confirm the issue hasn't reocurred since. Note that Resharper say they will be issuing a patch this week.

Comment: Seems to have solved it. Thanks for sharing the link with me and saving my sanity!

Comment: From the Resharper forum: `We're very sorry for the inconvenience. We're going to release 2021.1.5 with a fix for these problems (inlay hints and freezes) as soon as possible. As a workaround, please disable Inlay Hints in ReSharper | Options | Environment | Inlay Hints | General or downgrade to 2021.1.3.`

Answer (score 4):

This sometimes happens when an extension (typically a code analyzer) crashes with an exception (indicated by a status bar on top of the code window) while typing.

A workaround seems to be to open a pull-down menu, such as the File menu, and close it again.

I would call the resulting keyboard behavior a bug in Visual Studio, but the original cause is also always a bug in the extension you are using. You may therefore want to report it to both Microsoft and the developer of the extension. Note that this is my personal opinion. I do not work for Microsoft.